# Infinite bubble loop with CSS and set z-index

Tags: html, css, keyframe

I have a problem, when infinite my bubble the text always in front of bubble. Here is my code

```css
.main {
  background: green;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.bubble {
    position:absolute;
    animation-duration: 2.5s;
    animation-name: slidein;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.bubble_text {
    background: yellow;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
}

@keyframes slidein {
    from {
      bottom: 8px;
      right: 36px;
      width: 0;
    }
  
    to {
      bottom: 8px;
      right: 28px;
      width: 160px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="bubble">
    <div class="bubble_text">Hello world hello</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

how to solve the bubble (yellow color) so that its position is fixed when infinite from keyframes. and the text can be in the back position when the bubble closes?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's very hard to undertand what exactly you're trying to achieve. Can you rephrase to make it a bit clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if I got this right from your question... If so, a simple `overflow: hidden` on the **.bubble** element should do the trick.

```css
.main {
  background: green;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.bubble {
    position:absolute;
    animation-duration: 2.5s;
    animation-name: slidein;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bubble_text {
    background: yellow;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
}

@keyframes slidein {
    from {
      bottom: 8px;
      right: 36px;
      width: 0;
    }
  
    to {
      bottom: 8px;
      right: 28px;
      width: 160px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="bubble">
    <div class="bubble_text">Hello world hello</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the overflow text as below:
Notice `overflow: hidden;` added to the `.bubble_text` class.

```css
.main {
  background: green;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.bubble {
    position:absolute;
    animation-duration: 2.5s;
    animation-name: slidein;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.bubble_text {
    background: yellow;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes slidein {
    from {
      bottom: 8px;
      right: 36px;
      width: 0;
    }
  
    to {
      bottom: 8px;
      right: 28px;
      width: 160px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="bubble">
    <div class="bubble_text">Hello world hello</div>
  </div>
</div>
```